# Widget stops sometimes

Tags: android, widget

I have created a widget which show countdown at every second.
But sometimes randomly its stops and never starts, i have to remove it from screen and again add to home screen will do it start.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final AppWidgetManager mngr = appWidgetManager;

    new CountDownTimer(endTime.getTimeInMillis(), 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            updateClockValues(c, mngr);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        }
    }.start();

}

private void updateClockValues(Context context, AppWidgetManager mngr) {

    System.out.println("update widget function");
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = mngr;
    ComponentName thisWidget;

    final long sec = // some code to find seconds...and other values

    // Get views for widget
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widgetxml);
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, BreakingDownWidget.class);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rlMain, configPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtSec, sec);

    // Update widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

}
```

Any one can tell me, how to start widget again when getting focus, sometimes after switching between screens will stop this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think android kills the widget activity thats why you need to restart it.. i think you must register your widget application with some kind of services like alarm service

Answer (score 2):

> I have created a widget which show countdown at every second.

Please do not do that. You are wasting the user's CPU time and battery life. App widgets are designed to be updated every few minutes, not once per second.

> But sometimes randomly its stops and never starts, i have to remove it from screen and again add to home screen will do it start.

Of course. An `AppWidgetProvider` is a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. These components are supposed to live for a few milliseconds, long enough for `onReceive()` to complete, then go away. Android can and will terminate your process afterwards, if it needs the RAM. Your `CountDownTimer` is forking a background thread, which is not supported from a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.